# Why doesn't my tanked hot water heater require frequent maintenance?

Tags: hot-water, hot-tub

Hot tubs need frequent maintenance:  Maintaining PH levels, cycling/filtering, cleaning, etc.  However, a tanked hot water heater needs none of that.  Some of it makes sense: a hot tub is more likely to have contaminants introduced into its system.  However, even when a hot tub is unused and covered, the advice (as far as I can tell) is still that this maintenance is still required.

The primary reason I could think of why this might be the case is that hot water heaters are frequently circulating their water.  When somebody takes a hot shower, several gallons leaves the heater, and get replaced with brand new fresh water.  Does that mean that if somebody goes on vacation for a month, they should recirculate the tank to clear out built up microorganisms and rebalance PH levels?  Is there some minimum level of usage that hot water heaters need?

Comment: How hot is the water in the tank? Do you have extremophiles from a seafloor thermal vent in your water supply? Does your water supply have volatile antimicrobials added, such as Cl, Br or O3, that evaporate from an open bath?

Comment: Are those actually the answers?  If so, I'd definitely love an answer indicating as such.  (It also brings up other questions like why hot tubs are using volatile antimicrobials.  Maybe it all comes down to temperature?)

Comment: Other questions should be asked as -- you guessed it -- other Questions, if you actually want answers. (There is one, but it's offtopic here.)

Comment: hot tubs have food in them; skin cells, mucus, fecal matter, leaves, bugs, dust, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The water supply in your house - including cold water, water heater and hot water - is a closed system. Water comes in under pressure and there is normally no air in the system. If you are on a municipal water system then the water coming in is normally heavily treated - filtered, chlorinated, etc. - to remove and/or kill anything that might have been living in the original water source. Is that an absolute guarantee of "no problems"? Unfortunately, no it is not.

In fact, there is an ongoing question of how high to set your water heater. Set it to the typical minimum "hot enough" temperature of 120 F and you kill most bacteria but not everything. In particular, Legionella can grow above 120 F. [The CDC recommends 140 F](https://www.cdc.gov/legionella/wmp/control-toolkit/potable-water-systems.html) as the safe temperature. However, that increases [the burn risk of hot water](https://www.cdc.gov/legionella/wmp/control-toolkit/potable-water-systems.html). 120 F - safe for your skin, but not safe from Legionella. 140 F - safe from Legionella but can burn your skin in 5 seconds, even faster for young children!

One good solution is to use thermostatic mixing valves. These combine hot and cold water so that your hot water can be really hot (140 F) but the output will stay safe. Unfortunately, they add cost and complexity and another point of failure (fail hot and you get burned, fail cold and people complain and remove the valves rather than fixing them).

But the bottom line is that with at least 120 F and a closed system, *normally* hot water heaters don't need the kind of maintenance that a hot tub needs. The water gets much hotter than a hot tub and both starts out and *stays* relatively clean. Even a covered hot tub can easily grow things that start out in the air, and the a hot tub that is a comfortable temperature for people is also a comfortable temperature for bacteria.

Comment: In addition, some modern heaters have built-in periodic maintenance where they heat the water way up to kill everything in it. For ones that do not, it is advised to perform the heat kill once in a while.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to worry about microorganisms, because you're following CDC advice and running the hot water tank hot enough to kill them.

On maintenance, *there is maintenance*.  You should be purging scale out of the tank at intervals. You should be checking and renewing the sacrificial anode.  "annual" is not unreasonable.

Don't forget, a hot tub is stagnant.  The water that was in there yesterday is the same molecules of water that are in there today.  If you named them all, Chuck was there yesterday and will still be there tomorrow.

Whereas in a water heater, water is moving on through - and [they're designed to ensure turnover](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bm7L-2J52GU). Yesterday's water molecules went down the drain in yesterday's shower. Bye bye, Chuck!  Thus, the "pool chemicals" ARE being renewed; they come with the new water supplied by the city (chlorination etc.)